# JSON serialization using Marshmallow - skip None attributes

Tags: json, python-3.x, serialization, marshmallow

I am using Marshmallow to send instance of my Decision class to JSON. However, this will also dump the attributes which are `None`, e.g. my attribute `score` will translate to `null` in JSON. After that I am unable to read the JSON again using the same approach.

https://repl.it/repls/VoluminousMulticoloredFacts

The last line is where it currently fails. I need to either NOT dump `None` to JSON or skip `null` during loading:

```
import json
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load

json_data = """{
    "appid": "2309wfjwef",
    "strategy": "First Strategy"
}"""

# Output class definition
class Decision(object):
    def __init__(self, appid = None, strategy = None, score = None):
        self.appid = appid
        self.strategy = strategy
        self.score = score

class DecisionSchema(Schema):
    appid = fields.Str()
    strategy = fields.Str()
    score = fields.Int()

    @post_load
    def make_decision(self, data):
        return Decision(**data)

# Deserialization into object
dec_json = json.loads(json_data)
schema = DecisionSchema()
dec = schema.load(dec_json).data

print(dec.strategy)

# Dump results back to JSON
schema = DecisionSchema()
out = schema.dumps(dec)

print(out.data)

# Load back from dump
schema = DecisionSchema()
dec = schema.load(out).data

#print(dec.strategy) # returns error currently
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An "official" answer from marshmallow development team can be found in [this comment](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/229#issuecomment-134387999) in the bugtracker:

Use a `post_dump` method.

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_dump

class BaseSchema(Schema):
    SKIP_VALUES = set([None])

    @post_dump
    def remove_skip_values(self, data, **kwargs):
        return {
            key: value for key, value in data.items()
            if value not in self.SKIP_VALUES
        }


class MySchema(BaseSchema):
    foo = fields.Field()
    bar = fields.Field()


sch = MySchema()
sch.dump({'foo': 42, 'bar': None}).data  # {'foo': 42}
```

As I point out in [a further comment](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/229#issuecomment-363250656), there's a shortcoming: it will also remove `None` when the field's `allow_none` is `True`.

Comment: Another issue with this is that it will mess with your field order if you use
ordered = True

Comment: Sure. The method can be modified to keep the order and return an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Nice. Since version `post_load` always passes argument `many`, so method shall look like  `def remove_skip_values(self, data, many):`

Comment: Yes, since marshmallow 3, decorated methods must accept **kwargs.

Answer (score 3):

As I pointed out in my comment above this messes with the order if you use the

```
class Meta:
    fields = (
        'field1', 'field2'
    )
    ordered = True
```

To fix this I used this:

```
# Remove None fields
@pre_dump
def remove_skip_values(self, data):
    return {
        key: value for key, value in data.items()
        if value is not None
    }
```

This works for my dictonary of objects

Comment: This is more solid choice! Should be the accepted one to me!

Comment: can we make it optional thru a initial param `remove_none` eg MySchema(remove_none=True).dump(obj) ?

Comment: I get an error: `remove_skip_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'`

Comment: @chrisinmtown: I got the same. I fixed it by adding `**kwargs` to the list of parameters for `remove_skip_values`.

Additionally, I found that using `@pre_dump` conflicted with a post_load hook that I have that transforms the data into an instance of a class. Switching to `@post_dump` fixed this.